# How to filter sendDataMessage receivers so they respect port

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, smsmanager

The Android API for sending "data" SMS messages is `sendDataMessage()` which takes a port parameter. In the receiving app's `AndroidManifest` you can specify what port your receiver is listening on. I'm finding, though, that when I have multiple apps on the target device, each listening on a different port, every incoming message is broadcast to all of them.

I suspect I'm doing the filter incorrectly. Here's my filter, and my sending code. Any ideas?

From AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="NBSReceiver" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    <data android:scheme="sms"
          android:port="@string/nbs_port"
          /> 
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Sending code:

```
    SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    short nbsPort = (short)Integer.parseInt( getString( R.string.nbs_port ) );
    byte[] bytes = "A message".getBytes();
    smgr.sendDataMessage( phone, null, nbsPort, bytes,
                          null, null );
```

In the intent-filter I've tried putting the name and scheme in separate data elements, and also adding `android:host="*"`. It makes no difference. Some combinations block all incoming messages, but if I set the filter up so it gets messages sent to nbs_port it will also get messages sent to other ports. And my other apps registered on other ports get messages for this one.

Finally, the receiving code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ( action.equals("android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED") ) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if ( null != bundle ) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get( "pdus" );
            SmsMessage[] smses = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for ( int ii = 0; ii < pdus.length; ++ii ) {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[ii]);
                if ( null != sms ) {
                    String phone = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                    byte[] body = sms.getUserData();
                    Log.d(Tag, "onReceive(): got " + body.length
                          + " bytes from " + phone );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've googled around and searched here but haven't found anybody reporting the same problem, which suggests that either nobody's using `sendDataMessage()` or that I'm doing something really dumb. I hope somebody can point it out.

(I'm using GSM phones, of course. `sendDataMessage()` doesn't work at all on CDMA.)

Thanks!